# Web event App with API (since Facebook Event by API unavailable)

Tags: api, facebook

I have an app that used to create events on Facebook through the API when users organised them. [create event was removed from the API in v2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

Can anyone suggest a good, free, web-based (OS independent) event app that:

1. allows events to be created by API
2. lets users join event very easily with Facebook, Twitter and/or Google account
3. allows events to be shared very visibly on FB, etc.

In sum, I want a slick replacement to events that I can make from my app! Please help..

Comment: Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information and [edit] your question. What OS, what price? And edit your list layout.

Comment: I  assume that you would like it to be platform independent.

Comment: Yes, have edited. What's wrong with the list?

Answer (score 2):

Google has an events API [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events?hl=en)

From the about events page:

> A user can invite other users to an event by including them in the
>   attendees event property when inserting or updating the event. Each
>   attendee will see a copy of the event in their calendar. By setting
>   the sendNotifications parameter in the insert or update request to
>   true, the attendees will also receive an email notification. The user
>   that owns the original event is called the organizer of the event.
>
> The attendee copy of the event has the same event ID as the organizer
>   copy, and most of its properties are identical, except for private
>   properties of the event such as event reminders, colorId,
>   transparency, or the extendedProperties.private property. Whenever the
>   organizer changes any of the shared properties, such as the event
>   start time, summary or location, the change is reflected in each
>   attendee's copy of the event. The attendees can also change the shared
>   properties of the event, but the changes are only reflected on the
>   attendee's own copy. The only event change that is propagated from the
>   attendees back to the organizer is the attendee's response status,
>   stored in the attendees[].responseStatus property.
>
> The events.import method adds a private copy of an event to a given
>   calendar. No other users specified in the attendees[] or organizer
>   property will receive a copy of the event on their calendar.
>
> The organizer of an event can be changed using the API method
>   events.move. The actor performing the method must have write access to
>   both the source and target calendars.

- Easily shared with Google users
- Can be published to plus.google.com
- Invite only or can add self, *can also limit numbers*,
- Integrates with google calendar